# How to rename exported environment variable in docker

Tags: docker, environment-variables

Imagine I have an application (for which I can't modify the code source itself) in a container which is waiting for

- `DB_USR`
- `DB_HOST`
- `DB_PASSWD`
- `DB_NAME`

as environment variable to do a connection to a MySQL database
So I link this container to a MySQL container

but the environment variable names from the MySQL container exported to my application containers does not match.

Right now the only way I've found to do this is by wrapping the application binary into a bash script with do a export of environment variables to make the match.

Is there any standard/better provided by docker to do this mapping ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run application in docker with the command:

```
docker run -d \
  -e DB_HOST=${MY_OWN_ENV_HOSTNAME} \
  -e DB_USR=${MY_OWN_ENV_USERNAME} \
  -e DB_PASSWD=${MY_OWN_ENV_PASSWORD} \
  -e DB_NAME=${MY_OWN_ENV_DBNAME} \
  your-application-container
```

and of course, the additional parameters necessary to run.

Alternatively, You can create file env.txt with environment variables:

```
# Definitions of environment variables
DB_HOST=${MY_OWN_ENV_HOSTNAME}
DB_USR=${MY_OWN_ENV_USERNAME}
DB_PASSWD=${MY_OWN_ENV_PASSWORD}
DB_NAME=${MY_OWN_ENV_DBNAME}
```

and then run the application in a docker with the command

```
docker run -d --env-file ./env.txt your-application-container
```